# Why is this method console printing different results on server and client?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a button that allows saving a restaurant. In the method below I am trying to figure three things:

- if user already has a document,
- if this item is in the list,
- or not.

The code is:

```
'saveRestaurant': function(restId){
    check('restId', String);
    if(Meteor.userId())
    var hasSaved = SavedRestaurants.findOne({userRefId: Meteor.userId()});
    var isSaved = SavedRestaurants.findOne({userRefId: Meteor.userId(),savedRestaurants: {$in: [restId]}});
    if(isSaved){
        console.log('isSaved', hasSaved._id);
        return SavedRestaurants.upsert(
            hasSaved._id,
            {$pull: { savedRestaurants: restId}}
        );

    }
    else {
        if (!hasSaved) {
            console.log('!hasSaved');
            return SavedRestaurants.insert(
                {userRefId: Meteor.userId()},
                {$addToSet: {savedRestaurants: restId}}
            );
        } else {
            console.log('hasSaved && !isSaved', hasSaved._id);
            return SavedRestaurants.upsert(
                hasSaved._id,
                {$addToSet: {savedRestaurants: restId}}
            );
        }
    }
}
```

On the server console I get:

> `isSaved oYcsPz6ieoKrBMNkv`
>   `hasSaved && !isSaved oYcsPz6ieoKrBMNkv`

Which is as expected, but on the browser console I always get:

> `!hasSaved`

And the button is not showing the expected changed status. (saved, not saved)
the methods file is in the lib folder. (client/server)

So, I guess there is a "loop" here which overwrites something, but I don't get it.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Does the client have all data necessary to check if the restaurant is saved? If you do not publish this data, the client will not be aware that the data exists and thus, as your code says, will try to generate it.

Comment: as far as I can tell, yes, the collection is published with no filters and the template is subscribed to it.

Comment: Alright, I did missed something in the publication. It's working now, thanks a lot!.

Comment: In that case, your question is off-topic as non-reproducible as per the [help/on-topic]. It won't be very useful for future visitors, you may want to delete it.